# webpack: inline css only in home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, webpack

I am currently using the "extracttextplugin" to move the entry chunk css into a separate output CSS file. What I would like to do or know is if Webpack is capable of inlining certain chunks of CSS into the header?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the HTMLWebpackPlugin and StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /^(?!.*\.critical).*\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
    { test: /\.critical\.css$/, loader: StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin.inline() }
  ]           
},

plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
  new StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin()
]
```

See GitHub: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/issues/294